# Multiple PivotTables from same data source

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make multiple PivotTables from the same data source. I would like the PivotTables to be on separate worksheets. As of right now, I have a macro to create one PivotTable and format it how I'd like, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to make multiple. The only differences between the PivotTables will be which filters are selected.

This is the code that I have to make one PivotTable. I know I'll have to take out the Worksheets.Delete line, but when I tried to do that and add more worksheets, I got errors, so I'll just provide the code that has worked for one. If anyone has suggestions on what changes to make in order to make multiple, that would be great. Thanks!

```
Sub PivotTable()

'Declare Variables
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Data")

'Define Data Range
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="ExpensePivot")

'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="ExpensePivot")

'Insert Filter Fields
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ExpensePivot").PivotFields("month_number")
.Orientation = xlPageField
.Position = 1
End With

'Insert Row Fields
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ExpensePivot").PivotFields("charge_cc")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ExpensePivot").PivotFields("summary_point_18")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 2
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ExpensePivot").PivotFields("cost_element_description")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 3
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ExpensePivot").PivotFields("cost_element")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 4
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ExpensePivot").PivotFields("description")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 5
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ExpensePivot").PivotFields("vendor_name")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 6
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ExpensePivot").PivotFields("employee_name")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 7
End With

'Insert Column Fields

'Insert Data Field
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ExpensePivot").PivotFields("Amount")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 1
.Function = xlSum
.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
.Name = "Amount" 'Changed Revenue to Amount
End With

'Remove Subtotals
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ExpensePivot").PivotFields("cost_element"). _
        Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, _
        False, False)
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ExpensePivot").PivotFields("description"). _
        Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, _
        False, False)
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ExpensePivot").PivotFields("vendor_name"). _
        Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, _
        False, False)

'Highlight subtotals
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ExpensePivot").PivotSelect _
        "cost_element_description[All;Total]", xlDataAndLabel, True
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
        .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ExpensePivot").PivotSelect _
        "summary_point_18[All;Total]", xlDataAndLabel, True
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ExpensePivot").PivotSelect "charge_cc[All;Total]", _
        xlDataAndLabel, True
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

'Format Total Column with Commas
    Columns("I:I").Select
    Selection.Style = "Comma"


End Sub
```

Comment: Get your added pivot sheet the way you want it and then add copies of it as new sheets?